# Unix method to remove last 4 columns from csv file

Tags: csv, awk, sed, cut

Is there a way to use bash to remove the last four columns for some input CSV file? The last four columns can have fields that vary in length from line to line so it is not sufficient to just delete a certain number of characters from the end of each row.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cut can do this if all lines have the same number of fields or awk if you don't.

```
cut -d, -f1-6 # assuming 10 fields
```

Will print out the first 6 fields if you want to control the output seperater use --output-delimiter=string

```
awk -F , -v OFS=, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF-4;i++){ printf $i, }; printf "\n"}'
```

Loops over fields up to th number of fields -4 and prints them out.

Comment: in the awk line, I guess you want to printf $i not print $i, right? typo maybe? and `print $i ,` won't work, you may want to have `;` another typo?

Comment: @kent yeah meant printf $i, don't you need to have the ; if only one command.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean. The comma is expanded to the value of the OFS variable

Comment: This is not a robust method as you might have quoted fields with commas inside `"field1",field2,"field 3 with , comma",field4`

Answer (score 18):

```
cat data.csv | rev | cut -d, -f-5 | rev
```

`rev` reverses the lines, so it doesn't matter if all the rows have the same number of columns, it will always remove the last 4. This only works if the last 4 columns don't contain any commas themselves.

Comment: This is a really nice solution in my opinion, +1 for the use of rev (I didn't know it existed)

Comment: I get `rev: stdin: 0: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character`

Comment: Seems my file is a Windows csv file with `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text`. I had to use `awk` in the end (for other reasons.)

Comment: shouldn't this be `-f5-`?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `cut` for this if you know the number of columns.  For example, if your file has 9 columns, and comma is your delimiter:

```
cut -d',' -f -5
```

However, this assumes the data in your csv file does not contain any commas.  `cut` will interpret commas inside of quotes as delimiters also.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F, '{NF-=4; OFS=","; print}' file.csv
```

or alternatively

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{NF-=4;print}' file.csv
```

will drop the last 4 columns from each line.

Comment: Good way to drop the extra columns, but for me this replaces the commas between columns with spaces in the output. Is there an easy way to avoid that and keep them as commas?

Comment: You can add back your delimiter with awk -F, '{NF-=4; OFS=","; print}'

Comment: Great, that works for me. Also could set `OFS` in a `BEGIN` block or with the `-v` command-line argument like `awk -F, -vOFS=, ...`

Comment: This method only works for GNU awk. According to Posix, changing NF is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @kvantour tiny correction regarding "**changing** NF": incrementing `NF` would be defined behavior (a new field populated with an empty string is added), it's just decrementing `NF` that's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(,[^,]*){4}$//' file
```

Comment: In my sense, it is the best answer here!

Answer (score 3):

None of the mentioned methods will work properly when having CVS files with quoted fields with a <comma> character. So it is a bit hard to just use the <comma>-character as a field separator.

The following two posts are now very handy:

- [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)
- [[U&L] How to delete the last column of a file in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/234432/273492) (Note: this is only for GNU awk)

Since you work with GNU awk, you can thus do any of the following two:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS="," 'NF{NF-=4}1'
```

Or with any awk, you could do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ere="([^,]*|\042[^\042]+\042)"
             ere=","ere","ere","ere","ere"$"
       }
       {sub(ere,"")}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk one-liner:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=0;++i<=NF-5;)printf $i", ";print $(NF-4)}'  file.csv
```

the advantage of using awk over cut is, you don't have to count how many columns do you have, and how many columns you want to keep. Since what you want is removing last 4 columns.

see the test:

```
kent$  seq 40|xargs -n10|sed 's/ /, /g'           
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40

kent$  seq 40|xargs -n10|sed 's/ /, /g' |awk -F, '{for(i=0;++i<=NF-5;)printf $i", ";print $(NF-4)}'
1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6
11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16
21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26
31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk solution in a hacked way

```
awk -F, 'OFS=","{for(i=NF; i>=NF-4; --i) {$i=""}}{gsub(",,,,,","",$0);print $0}' temp.txt
```