# Unable to remove last field CSV file

Tags: shell, awk

i have csv file contains data like, I need to get all fields as it is except last one.

```
"one","two","this has comment section1"
"one","two","this has comment section2 and ( anything ) can come here ( ok!!!"

gawk 'BEGIN {FS=",";OFS=","}{sub(FS $NF, x)}1'
```

gives error-
    fatal: Unmatched ( or (:

I know if i remove '(' from second line solves the problem but i can not remove anything from comment section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [bash method to remove last 4 columns from csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418511/bash-method-to-remove-last-4-columns-from-csv-file)

Comment: The 3 characters important to include in an example of a field that can contain "anything" in a quoted-fields CSV are `,`, `"`, and `\n` (a literal newline). Include those in your example if you really do mean "anything" when you say it or clarify what you mean by "anything" otherwise.

Comment: The example given allows `cut -d"," -f1-2` as an approach, when you can have `...,"a field with , inside",...` please make this clear.

Comment: Thanks Ed and Walter, sorry i do not mean anything can come here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any `awk` you could try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}{$NF="";sub(/,$/,"")}1'  Input_file
```

Or with GNU `awk` try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}NF{--NF};1' Input_file
```

Comment: There's no need to escape a `,` in a regexp, it's not a meta-character. That second script is undefined behavior per POSIX so it'd do different things in different awks.

Comment: Thanks Ravi and Ed .. this works fine for me. Please explain how below code works          
    awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS=","}NF{--NF};1'

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that *everything can come here*, you might also have a line that looks like:

```
"one","two","comment with a , comma"
```

So it is a bit hard to just use the <comma>-character as a field separator.

The following two posts are now very handy:

- [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk)
- [[U&L] How to delete the last column of a file in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/234432/273492) (Note: this is only for GNU awk)

Since you work with GNU awk, you can thus do any of the following two:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS="," 'NF{NF--}1'
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]*|\"[^\"]+\"";OFS=","}NF{NF--}1'
$ awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]*|\042[^\042]+\042";OFS=","}NF{NF--}1'
```

**Why is your command failing:** The `sub(ere,repl,in)` command of awk assumes that the first part `ere` is an extended regular expression. Hence, the bracket has a special meaning. If you want to replace fields which are known and unique, you should not use sub, but just redefine the field:

```
$ awk '{$NF=""}'
```

If you want to replace a string matching a field, you should do this:

```
s=$(number);while(i=index(s,$0)){$0=substr(1,i-1) "repl" substr(i+length(s),$0) }
```